# Smooth transition to fullscreen with ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a RecyclerView where each item has a video. I'm using ExoPlayer to play the video from the RecyclerView's adapter. When the user taps on the video, I want to transition the video to fullscreen seamlessly, i.e. without the video pausing and with a smooth animation from the RecyclerView adapter.

I've done some reading for other solutions online, but they are either (1) outdated, or (2) don't apply as nicely to RecyclerViews.

So my question is: How would it be best for me to transition a video playing in a RecyclerView to fullscreen seamlessly?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey @user1695123 by any chance did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you use a fragment for show video in fullscreen mode and you can see this sample code
[Fragment that shows a video in landscape mode](https://github.com/mostafaHemmati/videoPlayerSample/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/hemmati/namavatest/view/videoPlayerFragment/VideoPlayerFragment.kt)

Comment: This doesn't really explain how to transition the video from the RecyclerView to the fragment (and ideally share the same instance of ExoPlayer)